# How long did it take to make your WinXP App Vista-Compatible?

Tags: windows-vista, compatibility

"The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed."
Yes this is a subjective question.
It has no answer.

I was just wondernig if I was the only one.
So... was it painful?
I just want to hear some comments.

Jag

P.S. Of course, it all depends on the app size, the language it was written, good or bad programming habits, etc...

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to ask what you did to make your WinXP app Vista-compatible?

Comment: I think it's a great question, especially if you're worried about Windows 7

Comment: voting to close. this is a discussion not a (real) question.

Answer (score 1):

Very painful, and a cost of several days if not weeks over time...

We had a lot of code revolving around sessions and IPC.  So we were effected by the change of [session 0 isolation](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/vista/services.mspx).

For Vista x64 and 2008 x64 we also had some driver components that needed to be digitally signed with [authenticode](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/vista/services.mspx) now.  Which wasn't a requirement before.

We also ran into some trouble with some of our apps not having manifest files to specify that they needed to be run as an elevated process.

Answer (score 0):

I had to move some registry keys from HKLM to HKCU - that was all - and I was very happy about that.  About an hour or two.  Less than a day form when it was discovered to when we had it fixed and in the source tree.  Not sure of the line count on that C++ app.

Not huge, but not trivial

Answer (score 0):

Not much.  I worked primarily on a large app written in C++ and MFC.  We moved to VS 2008 before Vista (waiting for VS 2008 SP1, which saved a lot of trouble), and most things just simply worked.  There was one external library I found a slight problem with (compensating for old VC++ problems), but no big deal.

Except for a routine to grab a window and put it into JPEG format, which I narrowed down to a small stretch of standard code that was vetted by competent people both here and on the MSDN forum.  Eventually, that problem went away on my computer, so I couldn't pursue it, but it has cropped up on others.

So, I never know when the goblins are going to come and take the JPEGs away, but other than that the transition to Vista was smooth.